# Join array elements depending on the element's index

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have this array: `[ 'here', 'are', 'some', '123', 'data' ]`. I would like to join the elements before the `'123'` into a string and the elements after the `'123'` into another string to get these three strings:

- `'here are some'`
- `'123'`
- `'data'`

I get the index of `'123'` by `arr.index {|el| el =~ /\d{3}/ }`. I tried `join` method, but I didn't find a way to add some conditions. I developed a solution using `array.each { ... }` to manually join the elements. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = [ 'here', 'are', 'some', '123', 'data' ]
i = arr.index {|el| el =~ /\d{3}/ }

arr[0..i-1].join(' ') # => here are some
arr[i] # => 123
arr[i+1..-1].join(' ') # => data
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr.chunk{|e| (e =~ /\d{3}/) || false}.map{|a| a.last.join(" ")}
# => ["here are some", "123", "data"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
b = a.index {|el| el =~ /\d{3}/}
s = [a[0..b-1].join(" "),a[b],a[b+1..a.size-1].join(" ")]
```

So `s[0]`, `s[1]`, `s[2]` will be the 3 strings. Is this what you are looking for?